# how to change wordpress onepress service section paragraph value

Tags: wordpress

I can not find a way to edit or better say change the "Morbi in sem quis dui placerat ornare. Pellentesque odio nisi euismod in pharetra a ultricies." string.

It is in services section. There is a class called service title for which I set whatever value I have set and inside is a mentioned paragraf.

Have can I change that paragraph so that insted of "Morbi in sem quis dui placerat ornare. Pellentesque odio nisi euismod in pharetra a ultricies.", says line tha I want?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's too late for the answer but not least. 
I went through the same issue on wp version 4.9.8 with OnePress and did some customization in a file - `/root/wp-content/themes/onepress/section-parts/section-services.php`

Replace

```
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
```

To

```
<?php $moreLink = '<a href="' . esc_url( get_the_permalink() ) . '"> Read more...</a>'; ?>
<?php echo wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 20, $moreLink ); ?>
```

Here 20 is the characters limit.